# Problems presenting a second modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the moment my error says my view controller is already presenting null. I think i have the right idea with my below code, but I'm not implementing it correctly. Thanks for your help

```
  -(IBAction)datePicker
{
    //UIViewController *presenter = self.presentingViewController;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        /*
        UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard.storyboard"
                                                      bundle:nil];
        UIViewController* dateView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DatePickerViewController"];

         */

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"dueDateSegue" sender:self];
        //[presenter presentViewController:dateView animated:YES completion:nil];

        /*
        [self presentViewController:dateView animated:YES completion:^{

            UIBarButtonItem *saveDate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                         initWithTitle:@"Save Date"
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                         target:self
                                         action:@selector(labelDatePicker)];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveDate;
            pick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
            [pick setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,120)];
            //[pick addTarget:self action:@selector(done) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            //dateFieldText.delegate = self;
            //dateFieldText.inputView = pick;

        }];
         */

    }];

}
```

Comment: Are you dismissing a view controller when one is not actually presented?  Does the block run if there is nothing to dismiss?  The documentation for dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion suggests that the block won't run unless something is actually dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `datePicker` add the following line as the first line of code:

```
UIViewController *presenter = self.presentingViewController;
```

And then instead of :

```
 [self presentViewController:dateView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

try using:

```
 [presenter presentViewController:dateView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Btw just noticed that you are just using 'init' for dateView. What about the view it controls?

Comment: So I implemented your solution above, but it just displays a black screen. I'm using storyboard btw, so initwithnib wouldn't work. performwithsegue may work. I'll try that

Comment: Which view are you trying to present? From your code, dateView is just alloc-inited with no view (i.e its not initialized from any xib and neither is the view property set). What is the view associated with the `dateView` view controller?

Comment: It's a UIViewController. I'll update my code with what I have so far.

Comment: Yup. The view controller should be associated with a view. If you are using an xib then instead of just usin init, use `[[DatePickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourXibName"];`

Comment: But if I'm using storyboard, there's no xib.

Comment: And from the new code you are changing two view controller back to back. That is the `performSegue...` method will change the view (and the associated view controller ) and so will the `presentViewController..` method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26306/discussion-between-rakesh-and-stangmmx)